# How to used NetworkBehavior in Unity3D

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine

Check the Picture- [Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLISf.png)

I made a c# script then change the MonoBehavior to NetworkBehavior
then pud the script in the Main Camera.

I have problem using NetworkBehavior I dont know how to execute it, I want to try the SyncVar and other attributes that can help about server-client data networking.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell what is going on from you picture, and it would be helpful if you could tell us exactly what you are looking for, but as far as SyncVar working, it is important to note that it only works from the server side. That is, you can't sync an attribute from a remote player to the server, but the server can sync a player's attribute to everyone else. another thing to note about sync var is that it only works on basic types and unity math types (quaternion, vector3, etc.) if I recall correctly. If you need more help please try to be more specific.

Comment: good day Ultimat0, thanks for your response.

Honestly, I want to have script about server/clients communication.

for example, server have the information on how many clients are connected, server will send the data to all the clients.

I found out that [syncvar], [clientrpc] or other attributes/functions can do this events. Using NetworkBehavior

but for now i want to know how [SyncVar] works
as you said, "SyncVar, it is important to note that it only works from the server side"

I want to know how clients and server communicate using [SyncVar]
how it works/process?

thanks.

Comment: @RyanJonesBayron What syncvar does is very simple: whenever the value of the variable with the syncvar attribute changes, that change is sent to all of the clients as well. For example: someone shoots you, you lose 50 health. That loss is sent to the server through an rpc, and the server syncs the health loss to everyone else.

Comment: so syncvar will automatic send the changes? then how client will receive that item? how client will know?

same in clientRPC. how Server receive that data? I dont understand how, 

i understand about networkserver.send, server will send type of message then you need to make a function in the client that if the client received that type of message (short value), then proceed for other code.

but in syncvar, command, clientRPC. i hace no idea.